# I get an error: VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:0 MEDIA_ERR_CUSTOM) When I play video using video.js

Tags: javascript, video.js

I could play an rtmp video stream using video.js before, but today suddenly I can't play. The console throws an error:

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE: 0 MEDIA_ERR_CUSTOM) MediaError {code: 0, message: ""}.
```

What caused `MEDIA_ERR_CUSTOM`? How to fix it?

The play source is no problem, and VLC media player can play normally with it.

```
src: "rtmp://192.168.135.217:10064/live/res=37.10000000001311000004.IV.0.0"
type: "rtmp/flv"

            <video
              id="my-video"
              ref={this.video}
              width="800px"
              height="500px"
            >
              <track kind="captions" />
              <source src={url} type={type} />
            </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your dev tools network tab to see if the media is being requested and returned? A few things to troubleshoot:

1. Ensure the video URL is correct and that the file is publicly accessible
2. Ensure that your CORS policy permits the domain you're requesting from
3. If using a flash fallback, you will need a crossdomain.xml file to permit the domain (similar to CORS) - be sure to clear your cache after correcting this as even a hard refresh may not reload it

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flash as a fallback or just using Flash and having this specific error:

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:0 MEDIA_ERR_CUSTOM)  MediaError {type: "FLASHLS_ERR_CROSS_DOMAIN", origin: "flash", message: ""}
```

Then you need to add or configure your ***crossdomain.xml*** file into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*.mycompany.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="*.speedtest.net" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

If it's the first time adding it on your app, this file goes in the root of the document folder on the server you want to allow access.
Ex: *http://speedtest.mycompany.com/crossdomain.xml*

and it should be added on your routing:

```
@web('/crossdomain.xml', 'template/crossdomain.xml')
def index(request): pass
```

More info about ***crossdomain.xml*** here:
https://support.ookla.com/hc/en-us/articles/234575708-What-is-crossdomain-xml-and-why-do-I-need-it-